# When did someone follow - Twitter API

Tags: twitter

I've been attempting to go over the Twitter API, albeit it has taken me a while and I'm being thrown back and forth between the old and the new site - however I was wondering if there is a date at all for when a user has decided to follow or; or if your able to tell when a user stopped following you?

I've been looking through here https://apiwiki.twitter.com/Twitter-API-Documentation to no avail, but I wondered if anyone knew of a way of doing it (outside of a separate monitoring system of course!)

Cheers,

Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Twitter API doesn't explicitly provide dates for when a user started following you or stopped following you.  This is something that you would need to monitor in some fashion.